# Octopress and github confusion

Tags: git, octopress

I'm new to Octopress and relatively new to git/github.

I cloned ([installed/setup](http://octopress.org/docs/setup/)) the Octopress repo locally:

```
git clone git://github.com/imathis/octopress.git sitename
cd sitename
bundle install
rake install
```

Cool - so now I have the source to Octopress and a skeleton site on my local drive.

#### Question 1 - Updating

According to the [docs](http://octopress.org/docs/updating/) I should be able to update to the latest Octopress changes via:

```
git pull octopress master     # Get the latest Octopress
bundle install                # Keep gems updated
rake update_source            # update the template's source
rake update_style             # update the template's style
```

but this results in an error:

```
[sitename]$ git pull octopress master
fatal: 'octopress' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Why is this failing?

#### Question 2 - Where does "my" stuff live?

Now I need to create my own github repo for the assets that I create, correct? If so, do I store *everything* there, or just the things that are specific to my blog (posts, pages, etc.)? My guess is that I have to create a repro at github and push my changes there... but again, I'm not sure if that is correct. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: In `git pull octopress master`, should that octopress also be replaced with sitename, like in the installation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In response to question 2:

Octopress repositories have two branches, *source* and *master*. The *source* branch contains the files that are used to generate the blog and the *master* contains the blog itself (your posts, etc.).

When the local folders are initially configured according to the [Octopress Setup Guide](http://octopress.org/docs/setup/), the master branch is stored in a subfolder named ‘_deploy’. Since the folder name begins with an underscore, it is ignored when you `git push origin source`. Instead, the *master* branch (which contains your blog posts) gets updated when you `rake deploy`.

You might find [this blog post](http://blog.zerosharp.com/clone-your-octopress-to-blog-from-two-places/) helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You should have a remote named `octopress` in your repo to do this:

```
[sitename]$ git pull octopress master
```

Try adding a remote named `octopress` and point it to https://github.com/imathis/octopress.git:

```
git remote add octopress github.com/imathis/octopress.git
```

Comment: "git remote add octopress https://github.com/imathis/octopress.git" added the remote so that now "git pull octopress master" seems to work. Wondering why this isn't part of the Octopress setup/install?

Answer (score 2):

The octopress documentation is a bit lax in places. It describes making the octopress remote when you use github pages as the deployment: http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/

This info should (I think) be added up front, as most people will likely want to maintain their blog in their own remote repo named `origin`.